# How to stop for loop from looping infinitely?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

In my version of Bootstrap there are 12 columns in a row.

In the below for loop each loop prints 2 columns wide.

What I want is that before the first column is printed (or `$i === 0`)`<div class="row">` is printed.

Then after the number of columns is equal to 12 (or the variable `$i` is no longer less than 6) for the closing row tag to be printed (`</div><!--row-->`) and then for the variable `$i` to be reset to zero.

I have achieved the layout I desire but the problem is that Wordpress is looping infinitely and retrieving the logo of the same company hundreds of times.

```
<?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) : ?>
        <?php if ($i === 0) : ?>
            <div class="row">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <?php $image = get_field('sponsor_logo'); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail-soft-crop'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/> 
                    </a>
                </div><!--col-md-2-->

                <?php if ($i === 5) : ?>
            </div><!--row-->

        <?php $i = 0;
        endif; 

    endfor; ?> 
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
```

Comment: So on which condition you want to exit from the loop.?

Comment: When there are no more companies to be retrieved from the Wordpress Loop. At the moment I only have two company logos but it is looping infinitely.

Comment: The problem is you are setting i=0 every time i gets to 5, so it never leaves that for loop.  I think you just want to kill the `i=0` line, so it'll exit the for loop, get back to the while loop to get the next post & the next image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring $i = 0; at the bottom so when the loop reaches bottom after increment it is again reset to 0 and hence running again and again.

If i am right i think you want to start a new row after number of iterations you can try this with some modification according to your requirement

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $i = 0;
    if ($i!=0 && $i%3==0){ // add new row after 3 posts
        echo "</div><div class='row'>"; 
        // close previous row after 3 elements and start new.
    }
    $i++;   
?>
```

Solution for Query in question.

`<div class="row">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $i = 0;
            if ($i != 0 && $i % 5 == 0) { // add new row after 5 posts
                echo "</div><div class='row'>";
            }
            $i++;
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <?php $image = get_field('sponsor_logo'); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail-soft-crop']; ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>`

Comment: I deleted the `$i=0` line which stopped the infinite loop, however now what is happening is the wordpress loop is retrieving company logo 1 and printing it 6 times and then closing off the row. It is then retrieving company logo 2 starting a new row and printing it 6 times before closing off the row.

Comment: use the code i mentioned above. Your code is doing so because it fetches a post from the while loop then it takes it to for loop and print it 6 times. for loop is not required here.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Excuse my ignorance but if you look at my code above that starts at `<div class="col-md-2">` and ends at `</div><!--col-md-2-->` where do I insert that code into your above solution?

Comment: When I don't set the variable $i to 0, $i successfully increments, however I get a php notice telling me I haven't declared the variable. When I do declare the variable $i to equal 0, I don't get any error messages but $i does not increment it just stays at 1. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: can you show your new code ? may be share a link of paste bin so i can look.

Comment: looks fine but i have made some very minor changes try this if it works.. http://pastebin.com/KW2Maz6p

Comment: I added that but didn't change it. I found the reason it is doing it. It's because every time it iterates through the loop $i is getting set to 0. Anyway, I can troubleshoot the rest from here you have set me on the right track. Thanks.